# Leaflet Map initialize same map/different centers

Tags: leaflet, maps

I have one single map displayed on different pages. I want to have the same map centered and zoomed differently depending on the page which displays the map.
I've tried to edit the code but it seems only one "L.map" is admitted:

```
 var map = L.map('single-map', {
    center: [20, 20],
    minZoom: 2,
    zoom: 5,
    scrollWheelZoom: false
});
```

anyone has an idea? Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set on each php page a global javascript variable to know on which page you are and change so the map settings

**page1.php**

```
<script>
var page = 'page1'; // change between homepage and page1
</script>
<div id="page1" class="map"></div>
```

**homepage.php**

```
<script>
var page = 'homepage'; // change between homepage and page1
</script>
<div id="homepage" class="map"></div>
```

And then you can switch between the settings depanding on the page:

```
var id, center, zoom;

switch(page){
    case 'page1':
    id = 'page1';
    center = [45, 15];
    zoom = 8;
    break;
  case 'hompage':
    // fall through
  default:
    id = 'homepage';
    center = [46, 15];
    zoom = 5;
    break;
      
}

var map = L.map(id, {
    center: center,
    minZoom: 2,
    zoom: zoom,
    scrollWheelZoom: false}
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/nLbp8d17/

Comment: can you please create a demo on jsfiddle? else i don't understand what you want

Comment: And what is now the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/2ue7nz5w/

Comment: Thank you for collaborating!
I'd like not to use 2 different maps ('map' and 'map2'). 
I need to initialize the same map ('map') on different pages using different IDs tag so I can change zoom and centering the map depending on IDs
<div id="homepage" class="map"></div> on homepage.php has certain coordinates and zoom
<div id="page1" class="map"></div> on page1.php has certain coordinates and zoom and so on...
I hope to be enough clear... sorry for misunderstanding...

Comment: @user15019578 I think I know what you want, but I don't understand why you want to do it like that. I updated my answer, you don't have to init both maps, change only the data which you are using

Comment: thanks for caring on this issue.
The reason is that I'd like to have the same map .js file to be shown on different pages but with different center and zoom level.
Where should I change the data? The map is loaded via 3 file: name.php (which shows the map and other contents) map.js (which creates the map with different polygons and icons) and leaflet.css (the original css of Leaflet).
I'd like to use only one .js file for the map (map.js) and, on the .php file which calls map.js, change the center and zoom. 
Thank you very much for you collaboration!

Comment: Add the switch in the map.js and the `<script>...</script>` part in the name.php. If it is not clear, please share your files over jsfiddle or so. It don't need to be a working demo only to show you the places for the code

Comment: It works! Thank you very much FALKE DESIGN!! :)
Now I'm able to show different zoom and centers on different pages but the .js map is always the same!! I've really appreciated you support, thank you again! :)

Comment: @user15019578 nice to hear, please accept the answer as correct